# Angular: BE response token and angular sets it with double quoutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

After BE response I have the following code:
`$cookieStore.put('Auth-Token', user.authToken);`
But in cookies I see
`Auth-Token: %220996dcbe-63e6-4d99-bd17-d258e0cc177e%22`
If I log it to console, I see `0996dcbe-63e6-4d99-bd17-d258e0cc177e`
How can I delete this double quotes?

Comment: When you read the cookie value you are getting it without double quote so I don't see any problem here.  What issue are you facing?

Comment: I dont think you can.  I am pretty sure that cookies are stored as strings

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Token is `0996dcbe-63e6-4d99-bd17-d258e0cc177e` and angualr sets it as `"0996dcbe-63e6-4d99-bd17-d258e0cc177e"`

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident and angular send header to BE in ""0996dcbe-63e6-4d99-bd17-d258e0cc177e"" format.

Comment: The token is a string so it will be stored in quotes.

Comment: The double quotes are because it is being stored as a string

Comment: http://take.ms/qVUaq cookie in the bottom does not stored with quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cookieStore` automatically serializes the value when it stores the value.  I think because of that it is adding double quote to already string value. I think you should use `$cookies` instead which do not do this.

`$cookies` doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies